# Choosing an ordered basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X = Y = \mathbb{R}^{3\times2}$. Let $T : X \to Y$ be the linear transformation given by $T(S) = RS$ where
$$R = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 10 & 0\\
0 & 2 & -2\\
4 & 2 &  8
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Choose ordered bases for $X, Y$ and compute the matrix $T$ with respect to these bases.

I'm not exactly sure how you would choose ordered bases for these matrices.
Could you just use the standard bases $e_{11}, e_{12}, \dots$?

Comment: Do you mean instead '*Choose ordered bases for $X,\, Y$*'?

Comment: yes, thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the standard basis (the same for $X$ and for $Y$), $e_{11},e_{12},e_{13},e_{21},e_{22},e_{23},e_{31},e_{32}.e_{33}$.